# AoT ERROR in RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Map.get (native) at StaticReflector.annotations

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When trying to do an `ng build --prod` on my project, it results in the following:

```
Date: 2017-09-17T16:03:06.816Z                                                     
Hash: d776bf985f9664cac088
Time: 3714ms
chunk {0} styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css (styles) 0 bytes {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} polyfills.3bc34265385d52184eab.bundle.js (polyfills) 86 bytes {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} main.e402deade8b026b7d50e.bundle.js (main) 84 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} inline.22b7623ed7c5ac6f9a35.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Map.get (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/chris/Documents/concord/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15542:64)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (/Users/chris/Documents/concord/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15502:52)
    at /Users/chris/Documents/concord/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15594:68
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/chris/Documents/concord/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15589:49)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (/Users/chris/Documents/concord/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15502:52)
    at /Users/chris/Documents/concord/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15594:68
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/chris/Documents/concord/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15589:49)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (/Users/chris/Documents/concord/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15502:52)
    at /Users/chris/Documents/concord/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15594:68
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/chris/Documents/concord/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15589:49)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (/Users/chris/Documents/concord/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15502:52)
    at /Users/chris/Documents/concord/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15594:68
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/chris/Documents/concord/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15589:49)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (/Users/chris/Documents/concord/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15502:52)
    at /Users/chris/Documents/concord/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15594:68
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/chris/Documents/concord/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15589:49)
```

Using the regular `ng build` or `ng build --env=prod` works fine, but whenever AoT is used, it fails. I've found many similar issues, but none of the solutions work or are applicable to my project.

- @angular/cli: 1.4.2
- node: 6.10.3
- angular: 4.4.1
- npm: 3.10.10
- os: macOS Sierra